# Optimal value is outside range when doing bruteforce optimization using Scipy

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

I'm following the example given in scipy's optimize [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brute.html) to do brute-force optimization on a function with 3 parameters.

This is the function I wish to optimize:

```
def entropy_of_hyperplane(z):
    w0, w1, b = z
    # do some calculations..
    return -1 * ent
```

To find the global minimum of this function using grid-serach, I do:

```
def find_max_entropy_hyperplane(X):
    # grid-search on all the possible w in R^2 , b in R
    # and calculate the entropy of each

    rranges = (slice(0, 2, 0.05), slice(0, 2, 0.05), slice(-4, 4, 0.25)) # ranges for w0, w1, b

    resbrute = optimize.brute(entropy_of_hyperplane, rranges, full_output=True,
                          finish=optimize.fmin)

    w0, w1, b = resbrute[0]
    print(w0, w1, b)
```

And the result is:
`w0 = 1.56; w1 = 1.1; b = 1842.73906893`

What is going on here? How is the optimal value of `b` outside the range I specified? I can't understand this behavior. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide the full code that reproduces your example?

Comment: The documentation, which you linked, says "Note that when finish is not None, the values returned are those of the finish program, not the gridpoint ones. Consequently, while brute confines its search to the input grid points, the finish program’s results usually will not coincide with any gridpoint, and may fall outside the grid’s boundary".  Try it with `finish=None` first.  As it is, you're employing a Nelder-mead simplex non linear optimization after `brute()` has found its "nearest best guess" and my theory is that is taking the result outside the boundary.

Comment: P.S. If you can give us the dataset you are using (or one that repros the problem), we can run it ourselves and verify - then I can write that up as an answer.